# Understanding of Django static files

Tags: python, django

I'm having the following issue. I've downloaded this project and trying to get it to work: http://sourceforge.net/p/etconf/git/ci/master/tree/

in `settings.py` there are following proeprties:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Actually, in the root of the project there is a folder `media`, inside which are subfolders `css` and `js`.

On the page there is this code:

```
{% block header %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/configurator.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/configurator.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And console log says:

```
[09/Oct/2015 12:23:50] "GET /media/css/configurator.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2245
[09/Oct/2015 12:23:50] "GET /media/js/prototype.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2230
[09/Oct/2015 12:23:50] "GET /media/js/configurator.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2239
```

What should I do? The project is in Python 2 and Django 1.1

To be clear, I'm not asking a best practive advice -- I'm fully aware that media and static files are different things and that django 1.1 is ancient, I just want to run this project, improvements would come later

Comment: Which server are you using? Development? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: It's going to be really hard to help you; the 1.1 documentation is no longer available and I can't remember what we did before the staticfiles app was included.

Comment: Personally, I'd think *very* carefully before installing an unsupported app, running on a framework version that is known to be insecure, to manage my computer's configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm aware of all that, I just need to run it and figure out how and why it works. We currently need to develop something very similar and we were thinking about upgrading this project to current technologies -- but first I need to see what it is and is it worth our time

Comment: I think the closest docs are 1.2.X on [readthedocs](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.X/howto/static-files.html), or source for 1.1.X is [in the repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.1.x/docs/howto/static-files.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the method for doing this has not really changed much after all. You just need to add the URL to your urls.py:

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),
```

changing /path/to/media to wherever your files actually are on disk.

Comment: adding this didn't change anything, and I tried both `{'document_root': '/media'}` and `{'document_root': '/media/'}`

Comment: found it! the `'document_root'` must not start with slash: `'media/'` worked great!